# Neo4j is taking more than one minute to complete the query

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j version 3.0.3. I have executed the below query for 100 000 data. It's taking more than one minute to execute. How to reduce the execution time?

```
MATCH (c:Consumer)-[:HAS_VISITED_LOCATION]-(l:Location) 
WHERE l.AreaName="hyderabad" OR l.AreaName="kanpur"  
WITH l 
MATCH(d:Consumer) 
WHERE NOT (d)-[:HAS_VISITED_LOCATION]-(l) 
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT d.MID)
```

Comment: Are you create index on `: Location(AreaName)`?

Comment: not yet created

Comment: Make them. And tell us about the result.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alternate approach. Since you only want the count of :Consumers who have not visited either location, we can get a count of those at the location, and subtract it from the total count of :Consumers.

```
MATCH (c:Consumer)
WITH COUNT(c) as consumerCnt
MATCH (c:Consumer)-[:HAS_VISITED_LOCATION]->(l:Location)
WHERE l.AreaName="hyderabad" OR l.AreaName="kanpur"
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT c) - consumerCnt as count
```

Edited so we get the count of all customers first. Neo4j is a little finicky on when it applies the NodeCountFromStore operation when it executes a query, so placing this at the beginning should guarantee this approach, instead of picking a different means that isn't performant.

Answer (score -1):

All the Consumers who have never visited Kanpur or Hyderabad

```
MATCH (d:Consumer)-[:HAS_VISITED_LOCATION]->(l:Location)
WHERE (l.AreaName<>"hyderabad" AND l.AreaName<>"kanpur")
RETURN COUNT(d.MID)
```

Comment: Well it is working for users those who are having the HAS_VISITED_LOCATION relation  but I also want  the count of users does not having the HAS_VISITED_LOCATION relation also.

Comment: try appending OPTIONAL keyword like this 

OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Consumer)-[:HAS_VISITED_LOCATION]->(l:Location)
WHERE (l.AreaName<>"hyderabad" AND l.AreaName<>"kanpur")
RETURN COUNT(d.MID)

Comment: This query won't work for consumers who have visited hyderabad and/or kanpur and other locations. For example, a consumer who has visted kanpur and who has visited chennai. The match considers the consumer and all locations they've visited. The row with kanpur will be filtered out. But the row with that same consumer and channai will be left in. `l`, the location, will be bound to the chennai location.

Comment: Also, returning the count of a node property is less efficient than getting the count of the node itself. It's a good idea to avoid unnecessary property access.